# How would I reference an external .py file containing an array, in another .py file, and use the array to retrieve information

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I am trying to retrive the data from an external array, to use in this program, but it gave me the error `IndexError: list index out of range`.

This is the example data I used:

```
[["James", 23], ["Jack", 27], ["Jimothy", 21],["Jillian", 22]]
```

And my example code:

```
import random

data = open('array.py', 'r').readlines()

randomInt= random.randint(0,4)

randomName = data[randomInt][0]
age = data[randomInt][1]

print(randomName, age)
```

in 2 separate files, and I was expecting it to output any of these 4:

```
>>>James 23
>>>Jack 27
>>>Jimothy 21
>>>Jillian 22
```

But instead I received
`IndexError: list index out of range`
How would I fix this? It still outputs the same error if I use `random.randint(0,3)`

Comment: `readlines()` returns a list of strings of each line in the file. The array only uses one line.

Comment: `data = open('array.py', 'r').readlines()` this code would never produce this list: `[["James", 23], ["Jack", 27], ["Jimothy", 21],["Jillian", 22]]`. Why are you opening a `.py` file from another script to begin with?

Comment: Also, note, `random.randint` has *inclusive bounds*. This is why a `random.randrange` was added with an exclusive upper bound, more in line with the typical python API which is designed around 0-based indexing

Answer (score 0):

You reading a `python` file as a text file & splitting accordingly. You don't even need to do that. Consider this example.

### array.py

```
arr_from_file_one = [["James", 23], ["Jack", 27], ["Jimothy", 21],["Jillian", 22]]
```

### Main.py

```
from array import arr_from_file_one

for x in arr_from_file_one:
    print(x)
```

Gives #

```
['James', 23]
['Jack', 27]
['Jimothy', 21]
['Jillian', 22]
>>>
```

> Note: You have to make sure that `array.py` and `main.py` should be on
> same folder.

Comment: I have replicated this code, but it says that it "cannot locate arr_from_file_one in array"

Comment: Make sure you assigned variable name correct in `array.py` ...& also make sure that variable name matches in `main.py` ...It should work...I've tested in my system..]

Comment: Sorry, I tried this in my original project and this works, but the exact code that you have given me gives me this error.

Comment: never mind, sorry forgot about this but I forgot to save the files first